Why do I need to use the spread operator?
I wanted to update a list of TextSpan whenever the user press a key.
I tried just passing the list to the children parameter, but it didn't work. I tried using the spread operator without changing anything else and It worked.
I wanna know what difference does this make? and why it did work when passing the list itself?
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  String testText = "Write something down";
.
  List<InlineSpan> userInputSpans = <InlineSpan>[
    const TextSpan(
      text: "Test1",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    const TextSpan(
      text: "Test2",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    const TextSpan(
      text: "Test3",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    const TextSpan(
      text: "Test4",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    const TextSpan(
      text: "Test5",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
  ];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: KeyboardListener(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        autofocus: true,
        onKeyEvent: (value) {
          // Only act on key presses
          if (value is! KeyDownEvent) return;

          setState(
            () {
              testText += value.character ?? "";
              userInputSpans.add(TextSpan(
                text: "Test",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple.shade400),
              ));
              userInputIndex++;
            },
          );
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Text.rich(
                TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    Text.rich(
                      TextSpan(
                      // children: userInputSpans, // Why doesn't this work and the line below does.
                      children: [...userInputSpans],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


because spread operator creates the new list, the same if you used List.of(userInputSpans)

@pskink Still doesn't add up to me. When the user press a key, the widget is rebuilt using setState. So it make sense to me when the widget is rebuilt, it will use the list with its newly added element.

but can you provide a wrong version? It can happen becuse flutter stores references to the list, and setState sometimes does not see changes in same values in the list because of nasty depth, it thinks that list wasn't been modified.  Thats why you have to create a new list like List.of(someList) or with spred operator, it takes another place in the memory and rebuilding detects it directly.

You mean that [...list] works but List.of(list) doesn't?

Can you clarify what "it didn't work" exactly means?  What happened?

@pskink No, I meant [...list] works but passing list by itself does not.

@jamesdlin So instead of showing the newly added elements, it doesn't show them at all. Only the initial values in the list.

this is because you are passing the same list in children: userInputSpans - if you want to know exactly why this happens then check this line: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/main/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart#L355 - if you set the breakpoint here you will see that it goes to case RenderComparison.identical: which is doing nothing
